# Script to batch find and replace specific text then add 3 spaces after the replaced text in .txt file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, text, fixed-width

I am fairly new to scripting and have searched around on the internet but cannot seem to find a specific solution for what I'm trying to achieve so I'm hoping someone could please shed some light.

I have a .txt file that contains various lines of data which is organised by text starting at specific column numbers - basically a table of data. See example below which shows where each column starts:

```
 |            |                                      |
 |1214000     |1234567890                            |ISRBWPX0001000001
 |            |                                      |
 |MD-3300     |+12345678912                          |MDABWPX0001000001
 |            |                                      |
 |            |                                      |
 |            |                                      |
 Col:620      Col:632                                Col:672
```

[Please click here for screenshot if above example makes no sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F5dy.png)

I want the script to find all lines which contains 'MD-' in column 620 and delete this so only the number is left. So I ran the Replace command in PowerShell which did delete all lines containing 'MD-' however it misaligned the rest of the columns;

PowerShell Command used:

```
(Get-Content "test.txt") | 
Foreach-Object {$_.replace("MD-", "")} | 
Set-Content "testedited.txt"
```

Output of above command:

```
 |            |                                      |
 |1214000     |1234567890                            |ISRBWPX0001000001
 |            |                                      |
 |3300     |+12345678912                          |MDABWPX0001000001
 |            |                                      |
 |            |                                      |
 |            |                                      |
 Col:620      Col:632                                Col:672
```

[Click here for screenshot if above example makes no sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAS9j.png)

As you can see '+12345678912' is no longer aligned with Column 632 as well as 'MDABWPX0001000001' which is no longer aligned with Column 672.

Is there a way to carry out the above command without affecting other columns? I read somewhere that Hash tables can do this however I did not completely understand the method.

Desired output:

```
 |            |                                      |
 |1214000     |1234567890                            |ISRBWPX0001000001
 |            |                                      |
 |3300        |+12345678912                          |MDABWPX0001000001
 |            |                                      |
 |            |                                      |
 |            |                                      |
 Col:620      Col:632                                Col:672
```

[Please click here to see screenshot of desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkAHK.png)

I am open to use any scripting languages / methods to carry out this task so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_ -replace '(?<=.{620})MD-([0-9]+)',('$1'+' '*3)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Just so I can understand it better, could you please break down the formula?

Comment: We look for the string `MD-` after a positive lookbehind `(?<=)` of at least 620 single characters `.{620}`, followed by one or more numbers `[0-9]+` which we capture using `()`. This match is replaced by the captured numbers `$1` and three spaces `' '*3`

Comment: Thank you, how would I go about applying your solution to multiple .txt files located in the same folder? I have been trying with `Get-ChildItem` but had no luck.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem C:\input -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    ((Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace '...') | Set-Content $_.FullName -WhatIf
}`

Comment: Thanks Nas, I tried the following: `Get-ChildItem C:\Users\jbagha\Desktop\FTPMultiDownload -Filter *.txt | 
ForEach-Object { ((Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace '(?<=.{620})MD-([0-9]+)',('$1'+' '*3) | 
Set-Content $_.FullName -WhatIf) }`

Comment: Which returned:

`PS C:\windows\system32> C:\Users\jbagha\Desktop\scripting\multiFiles2.ps1
What if: Performing the operation "Set Content" on target "Path: C:\Users\jbagha\Desktop\FTPMultiDownload\test2.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Set Content" on target "Path: C:\Users\jbagha\Desktop\FTPMultiDownload\test3.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Set Content" on target "Path: C:\Users\jbagha\Desktop\FTPMultiDownload\test4.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Set Content" on target "Path: C:\Users\jbagha\Desktop\FTPMultiDownload\test5.txt".`

Comment: Remove `-WhatIf` from the `Set-Content` cmdlet to actually execute that command. With `-WhatIf` it shows you what would happen and which files would actually be affected (and overwritten in this case). Take a backup of your txt files before removing the `-WhatIf` parameter

Comment: It worked perfectly after removing `-WhatIF` Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Nas, sorry to bother you... as your solution worked I was wondering if you could help with another script in relation to editing .txt files - Could you please visit my question and see if you can help - [Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53054634/10426268) Thank you in advance @Nas

Answer (score 1):

It is easy enough to do this with a -replace regex. I tested with 'MD' starting in the 11th column. Change it to 620, or whatever it needs to be.

```
(Get-Content "test.txt") |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '^(.{11})MD\-([^ ]*|)(.*)$', '$1$2   $3' } |
    Set-Content "testedited.txt"
```

Here is the test data and sample run.

```
PS C:\src\t\repmd> Get-Content .\test.txt
0123456789|asdf    |asdfdsaf
0123456789|MD-333  |asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqw    |asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqwasda|asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqw    |asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqw    |asdfdsaf
PS C:\src\t\repmd> .\repmd.ps1
PS C:\src\t\repmd> Get-Content .\testedited.txt
0123456789|asdf    |asdfdsaf
0123456789|333     |asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqw    |asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqwasda|asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqw    |asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqw    |asdfdsaf
```

The regex breaks down like this.

```
^        beginning of string
(.{11})  capture 1 - eleven (11) characters
MD\-     literal 'MD-' (the '-' character needs to be escaped with \
([^ ]*|) capture 2 - all non-space characters until a VERTICAL LINE
(.*)     capture 3 - all remaining characters
$        end of string
```

`'$1$2   $3'` produces the captured strings. The three (3) spaces before $3 replace the three (3) characters take out by 'MD-'.

Comment: This worked great too! Could you please breakdown the formula so I can understand it better.

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown, how would I go about applying your solution to multiple .txt files located in the same folder? I have been trying with `Get-ChildItem` but had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Change next line by 620 and 12
set /A "pos=11, wide=8"
set /A "posP3=pos+3, rest=wide-3, posPwide=pos+wide"

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (Input.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   if "!line:~%pos%,3!" equ "MD-" (
      set "line=!line:~0,%pos%!!line:~%posP3%,%rest%!   !line:~%posPwide%!"
   )
   echo !line!
)) > Output.txt
```

**Input.txt**:

```
0123456789|asdf    |asdfdsaf
0123456789|MD-333  |asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqw    |asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqwasda|asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqw    |asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqw    |asdfdsaf
```

**Output.txt**:

```
0123456789|asdf    |asdfdsaf
0123456789|333     |asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqw    |asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqwasda|asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqw    |asdfdsaf
0123456789|cwqw    |asdfdsaf
```